# How do I catch errors in a Bluebird Promise.each?

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise, bluebird

I have six promises in an array and I want to run through them sequentially because the last two are database queries where one depends on the other, but the first four it doesn't really matter. Anyway, I tried to run a `Promise.each` with a `catch` block attached to it:

```
    var promises = [promise1, promise2, promise3, promise4, promise5, promise6];
    Promise.each(promises, (value, index, length) => {
        return next();
    }).catch((e) => {
        console.log(e);
        return next();
    });
```

But I'm still getting:

```
Unhandled rejection Error: Cannot do X in Y
```

Alternatively, the first four promises can be run asynchronously, so I wanted to use a Promise.each nested in a Promise.all. I'm still testing this and it might work, but why would this work over a single `Promise.each`? How do I propagate errors if I only have a single `Promise.each`?

```
    var promises = [promise1, promise2, promise3, promise4];
    var promises2 = [promise5, promise6];
    Promise.all(promises, (result) => {
        Promise.each(promises2, (value, index, length) => {
            return next();
        }).catch((e) => {
            console.log(e);
            return next();
        });
    }).catch((e) => {
        console.log(e);
        return next();
    });
```

Comment: Promise.each won't wait for the previous to resolve. Run the first set and `then` run the dependent promises

Comment: Huh. What's the standard use case behind `Promise.each` then? What differentiates it from `Promise.all`?

Comment: The difference is that each accepts an iterator as param. But the promises don't run in order. Look at this: http://jsfiddle.net/ghmku3vs/

Comment: Best thing you can do is run the first 4 with `Promise.all(promises)` and inside the `then` run the other two the same way. Bare in mind that if any of those promises inside the `all` gets rejected, the whole explodes and you end up in the catch